# What are good open source PHP projects for beginners?

Tags: php

I'm looking into freelancing PHP projects on my spare time so I'm revisiting my rusty PHP skills. I believe contributing to an open source project could refresh me quickly. Also, if you have other suggestion please feel free to suggest. Thanks!

Comment: If you also like math you could also do some Project Euler problems (http://projecteuler.net) to refresh your programming skills.

Comment: closevoting because people will just name their pet open source project. too subjective.

Comment: also likely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288526/good-open-source-php-projects

Comment: @Lex: Looks interesting. I'll be sure to look into it some more. Thanks!

Comment: @Gordon: Thanks for the reference question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Drupal](http://drupal.org/) , [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/home) or [silverstripe](http://www.silverstripe.com/)

Comment: Thanks! I'm still open for other suggestions.

Comment: @cr8ivecodesmith I would like to add that Drupal and Silverstripe are PHP CMS'. If you were looking for a CMS, I would most def recommend Silverstripe. If you were looking for a PHP framework, I would recommend Laravel. I'm currently playing with it, and from what I've seen of it to now, it looks solid.

Comment: +1 for Silverstripe, depending on the type of projects it generally takes a lot of fuss out of development for the smaller web project. These days the CMS & Framework are separate so best of both worlds. Has cleaner more testable code than Drupal. I like Laravel too but in terms of speed of delivery I find SilverStripe the simplest.

Comment: I use Silverstripe for all my small business clients as I'm learning it my self. It's pretty easy to put together simple sites and teach people how to keep it updated. I looked at many other frameworks, but SS comes with everything built in.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [Laravel](http://laravel.com) - Its a rails like php framework thats been gaining a lot of traction lately.